# Comparison nauty vs. bliss of canonical form of bipartite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I need to compute **canonical forms** of *many* (~10^6-10^8) vertex-facets incidence graphs of polytope. Two rather big examples I want to consider are

- the [600-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/600-cell) with 120 vertices and 600 facets (dimension 4), and
- the smallest known [counter example](https://sites.google.com/site/christopheweibel/research/hirsch-conjecture) to the Hirsch bound with 40 vertices and 36426 facets (dimension 20).

The two options that seem to be best suited to compute these canonical forms are [nauty](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/implement/nauty/implement.shtml) and [bliss](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/).
My questions are

- Is there another option that I have overseen?
- I have not found any benchmark comparisons between the two, so should I prefer one over the other?
- Does the property of being bipartite make a difference in which to choose?

Many Thanks! -- this is not a strictly mathematical question, but I hope it is still suitable here.

The graphs that are test cases can be found in dreadnaut format here: [counter example to the Hirsch conjecture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1POEh8bhq1fajBOOXhYcjRIblU/view?usp=sharing), [600-cell](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1POEh8bhq1fUkpSMWJBaFNVajQ), and [1000 typical examples](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1POEh8bhq1fRTBDX0lvVG00dlk/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a comparison at http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it under the "experiments" link, and Traces is there too.  It's hard to tell in advance what will work best.  Either your graphs are like typical graphs of these sizes, in which case all the algorithms will be fast enough, or they are much harder, in which case some care is needed. If you send me a handful of typical examples in one of the two formats that are used at http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/Graphs.html , I will give more precise advice.

Comment: Great, thanks for the offer -- I will send you some graphs later today once I got them into the desired format!

Comment: It starts at vertex 0, so should have \$=0 not \$=1.  Also there are no line breaks in the file so some numbers are joined together.  After fixing it as I think it should be, nauty (sparse mode) finishes in 0.02 seconds.  It is easy because the vertices on the small side have a mixture of degrees. Vertex 40 (the first on the big side) has anomalous 40; should it?

Comment: @Christian : I don't have access to that file.  Also, you might have received an access request via gmail, but I don't use that address for email.

Comment: @Christian: The 600-cell is easy because the automorphism group is large. Sparse nauty 0.00055 sec, bliss 0.00141 sec, Traces 0.00061 sec.  For the previous large irregular graph: sparse nauty 0.013 sec, bliss 0.064 sec, Traces 0.019 sec.  A more difficult example would be highly regular without automorphisms.

Comment: I moved the links to the examples to the end of the question, so it becomes easier to find in case someone wants to find them.

Comment: @Christian: Sparse nauty takes 23 milliseconds to do all of them (23 microseconds each).  I don't have a script for doing them all in Bliss, but in any case you can see that your problem is actually an easy one.

Comment: Many thanks for testing this for me, @Brendan McKay!